# WPF DataGrid - how to stop user proceeding if there are invalid cells? (MVVM)

Tags: wpf, mvvm, wpfdatagrid

I'm implementing edit functionality in my DataGrid. The `CellEditingTemplate` of a typical cell looks something like this:-

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <TextBox Grid.Column="0" 
                 Text="{Binding Concentration, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, NotifyOnValidationError=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}"
                 Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource errorTemplate}" />
    </DataTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
```

In this example there is a TextBox bound to a property called "Concentration", which is a property of type double, with validation to ensure that it falls within a given range. The models that are being bound to the grid implement `IDataErrorInfo` by the way.

The problem is, although the error template highlights the cell when an invalid value is entered, there is nothing to stop me from moving focus away from that cell (or row). What's the preferred approach for handling validation with data grid editing? I wondered if I could prevent the user from leaving the cell until a valid value was entered, but that could be dangerous - they wouldn't be able to do anything (even close the app) until a valid value had been entered.

Another option might be to prevent the user from proceeding if the datagrid contains any invalid rows. But what's the best way to test this? IDataErrorInfo doesn't provide an "IsValid" property that I can examine on each of the rows' models.

Lastly I could just revert the model's property back to its previous "good" value (or a default value) if the user enters something invalid.

Any suggestions? I'm using MVVM by the way.

Comment: Can you post the code of how you implement iDataErrorInfo on your model.  Also, are you using any mvvm framework?  I track if my objects have errors and then disable navigation away from view until either error is corrected or changes are undone.

Comment: @JKing implemented in the "usual" way, via the `public string this[string columnName]` indexed property. I have a switch statement to look at the given columnName and validate the corresponding property's value, returning an error message if invalid. I'm not using any MVVM framework.

Comment: I like doing what @JKing showed below on my viewmodels. I add the Dictionary where the key is the property name and the value is the error string. I have an IDataErrorInfo implementation like yours, but I do it on my ViewModel (since that's where I bind to properties) and in `public string this[string columnName]` I add errors to the dictionary. I bind navigation controls to my HasErrors property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use this to see if IDataerrorInfo has any errors for the object, a small snippet of the implementation:

```
protected Dictionary<string, string> _propertyErrors = new Dictionary<string, string>();
public bool HasErrors {
    get { return (_propertyErrors.Count) > 0; }
}
```

Then I can handle the logic for what to do after evaluating this property.  Do you want to prevent navigation, closing app, etc.  Then you need to evaluate for errors from that code and then cancel that action.

Comment: I suspected it would be a case of managing some kind of "has errors" flag, but at the back of my mind hoped there might have been an out of the box solution. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I've used this method in the past to determine if a datagrid has errors:

```
private bool HasError(DataGrid dg,)
{
   bool errors = (from c in
                    (from object i in dg.ItemsSource
                     select dg.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(i))
                  where c != null
                  select Validation.GetHasError(c)
                 ).FirstOrDefault(x => x);
   return errors;
}
```

Then it's only a matter of preventing the next action if the method returns true.

Comment: That's a useful snippet but I have to go with J Kings answer as I'm using MVVM. So do you just show a message telling the user they must fix all validation errors in the DG before they can continue? I was hoping the DG might have better editing features, eg forcing the user to stay on the row until they fixed the error or "aborted" the edit in some way. Thanks for your reply though.

Comment: I guess you could loop through the controls until you find one with an error and force the focus on it.